# Repair Windows file system via liveUSB Ubuntu

Tags: windows

After auto-updating Windows drivers I can't start Windows, enter safe mode, and even reinstall Windows. It always crashes with a blue screen of death "system_thread_exception_not_handled (ntfs.sys)".

I have bootable USB Ubuntu and the computer works well with "Try Ubuntu" mode. And I want to fix problems in Windows via Ubuntu.

So I think I have the same problem like this:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/bsod-what-failed-ntfssys/63d790bc-15b4-40ea-a424-8a44897be576 . And as a solution in the end the author repaired file system via Ubuntu terminal. But how?

**SO MY QUESTION**:

How can i fix problems in Windows using Ubuntu? I'm ready to delete entire disc C: where is Windows located and reinstall it then.

Comment: why not just install Ubuntu and have done with windoze?

Comment: Use Windows tools to repair Windows filesystems. Since you are ready to reinstall you will have a bootable Windows installer which may be used for that purpose.

Comment: @mook765 Unfortunately I didn't find a solution to the problem using Windows environment. Bootable Windows USB also crashes with the same error

Comment: @graham I have never used Linux before. But it will be a fallback solution if I can't fix it

Comment: @MaksimD Linux tools like `ntfsfix` can fix some common problems and will schedule a filesystem check on next Windows boot. If you have serious problems you depend on Windows tools. If you cannot boot into Windows, not even in your bootable USB, it's nothing you can fix with Linux.

Comment: @MaksimD you'll be surprised at just how easy it is to seamlessly move to the Ubuntu desktop GUI from Windoze. Try Ubuntu from USB then install it.

Answer (score 0):

The command issued was

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/{device_name}
```

where {device_name} is your Windows disk. Use `fdisk -l` to find out what that is. The command is part of the `ntfs-3g` tool set. If not installed you can add it by doing

```
sudo apt install ntfs-3g
```

This will only fix a corrupted Windows NTFS. Nothing else. The tool is good but not perfect. Native Windows tools should be used if possible.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I've already tried this command before. It didn't work for me

Comment: then your hard disk is likely damaged and not the filesystem And if you did why is it not in the question?

Comment: @MaksimD If your drive is not encrypted, it may still be possible to access your files using the Ubuntu USB so you can back up what you need like photos and stuff before you switch to a new drive as I assume now you're going to buy a new SSD or HDD or whatever. Personally, I'd get an SSD because the performance is so much better and more reliable in my experience but I digress.

Comment: @MaksimD Like, even if the drive is really messed up you might still be able to salvage some files using digital forensic tools, even if some of the files are partially corrupt or missing the filenames.

Comment: @mchid Thanks. Yes, I was able to copy important documents from HDD using Linux. That`s why I thought that it isn't a hardware problem, but only Windows problem.

Comment: @MaksimD I found kind of a weird website that says it might be a driver issue? Possibly the file for the driver got corrupted maybe and so fixing the filesystem could be only step 1? I'm not sure because I don't use windows much. But I have repaired a non booting system before using a rescue dos environment (like bootrec and stuff). Not sure how you would go about checking drivers from a windows rescue session.